# Issue with css notification

Tags: php, html, css

Below is the html and css of notification which I want to use along with my php. https://jsfiddle.net/aogu8zdz/

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Write your error message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box success"><span>success: </span>Write your success message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box warning"><span>warning: </span>Write your warning message here.</div>
<div class="alert-box notice"><span>notice: </span>Write your notice message here.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-box{font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#555;border-radius:10px;margin:10px;padding:10px;}
.alert-box span{font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase;}
.error{border:1px solid #f5aca6;background:#ffecec;}
.success{border:1px solid #a6ca8a;background:#e9ffd9;}
.warning{border:1px solid #f2c779;background:#fff8c4;}
.notice{border:1px solid #8ed9f6;background:#e3f7fc;}
```

**Login**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="description" for="username">Username</label>
            <div>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="element text large" name="user_name" required/>
            </div>
            <label class="description" for="userpassword">Password</label>
            <div>
            <input type="password" id="userpassword" class="element text large" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LAAAAKOie0vP8_Ym5DGxs6SH"></div>
            <div class="alert-box success"><?php echo $login_message; ?></div>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button" name="login" value="Log in"/></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

You see the `$login_message` is where all notification like wrong password, username or logout success is displayed

The problem is that the css alert boxes should display itself once the `$login_message` is invoked by the application but it displays even without the message being invoked

**Login**

[image]

How do I display the notification boxes only when there is a message to display?

Comment: Hide it, when it has no message ?

Comment: @frz3993, the notification box.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the notification div is displayed is because, you are not checking whether the submit button is clicked or not.

This issue can be easily solved. Just Replace

```
<div class="alert-box success"><?php echo $login_message; ?></div>
```

with

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?>
    <div class="alert-box success"><?php echo $login_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

> isset() determines if a variable is set and is not NULL

**UPDATE**

Regarding @Brett's comment, instead of checking the `$_POST['submit']`, you can check for a success message and show the success notification, or else you can show an error notification. You just need to change the class of the notification.

Comment: this is sort of correct, I mean.. the state of `success` isn't simply because there is a `submit` keyvalue in form post..

Comment: also, the alternative is to do/design a client-side request and response system here.. handle the request and response in a separate php page.. that will allow you to decouple views from handlers (server-side code).. making things more scalable, reusable, and maintainable.. it's in line with the MVC notion.. but, yeah, it adds a dependency on client-side mechanics and javascript..

Comment: That is the efficient way of doing, but from the OP's post it is quite evident that he's not following an MVC pattern and thus it would be a really tedious work for him to rewrite the whole codes..

Comment: @RnD Did it help you ?

Comment: @Lal, give me sometime. I need to be sure. Though I know your solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add css class hidden:

```
.hidden_div{display:none;}
```

Then in html:

```
<div class="alert-box success <?php echo (!isset($login_message) ? 'hidden_div' : ''); ?>"><?php echo $login_message; ?></div>
```